# How to convert raw json objects into Json in python?

Tags: python

```
[{"changed_aspect": "media", "subscription_id": xxxx, "object": "user", "object_id": "xxxx", "time": "xxxxxx"}]
```

That's the data I get from the server.

jsondump = json.dump(data)

but when I do jsondump[1]["changed_aspect"] it doesn't show the value media. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What if you change that `[1]` to a `[0]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the subscription_id should have been a valid string,

```
>>> import json
>>> c = '[{"changed_aspect": "media", "subscription_id": "xxxx", "object": "user", "object_id": "xxxx", "time": "xxxxxx"}]'
>>> data = json.loads(c)
>>> data[0]['changed_aspect']
u'media'
```

The index should be 0, not 1 as lists in python are 0 based indexed.